# Setting more than one trigger with SCHTASKS command

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task, windows-task-scheduler

I want to add multiple triggers for the task I'm creating through `windows command line` interface. I went through the documentation for `schtasks create` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks-create) but it doesn't specify how we can do this, or even if we can or not at all.

An example of how I create a task with one trigger, specifically for `Every day at 23:00`:

```
SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC DAILY /ST 23:00 /TN "TaskName" /TR "D:\TaskDir\TaskName.exe taskArgument" /NP
```

I also want to set two additional triggers for `09:00` and `16:00`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To schedule the .eve task program, if for regular hours schedule in a day like for to run every 7 hours, for 24 hours total, according to the doc:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks-create#examples-1 , type:

```
SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC DAILY /ST 09:00 /TN "TaskName" /TR "D:\TaskDir\TaskName.exe taskArgument" /NP/sc hourly /mo 7 /st 00:00 /du 0024:00
```

Then, if for random time points, it cannot be achieved in a single script, it should be divided into three scripts like below:

```
SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC DAILY /ST 09:00 /TN "TaskName" /TR "D:\TaskDir\TaskName.exe taskArgument" /NP

SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC DAILY /ST xx:00 /TN "TaskName2" /TR "D:\TaskDir\TaskName.exe taskArgument" /NP

SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC DAILY /ST xx:00 /TN "TaskName3" /TR "D:\TaskDir\TaskName.exe taskArgument" /NP
```

[image]

Comment: Although a decent answer, not really the one I was looking for. But both with your answer and with my research, I've come to the conclusion of this thing not being possible without `\XML` argument to the `schtasks` command. So now, I create an XML and pass it into the `schtasks \create \tn "TaskName" \XML "C:\XmlPath"` which works.

Comment: @oividiosCaeremos Your solution is thoughtful for this issue and you can post your answer then highlight it to help benefit more developers here.